# error: package org.hamcrest does not exist Android Studio 1.5.1

Tags: android-studio, junit, hamcrest

I am using Android studio 1.5.1.
My build.gradle looks like below

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        }
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    dependencies {
        // Unit testing dependencies
        testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

I am writing some JUNIT test cases for my application as below

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

public void testSomething throws Exception {
        ...
        assertThat(result, is(true));
}
```

But when I am running the tests, it is showing that

> error: package org.hamcrest does not exist
>
> error: cannot find symbol assertThat(result, is(true));

But I can go to the definition of assertThat, org.hamcrest etc from studio by going to definition as studio decompiles the jars. 
Also I can see the package downloaded in .gradle/caches

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here?
Normally Junit test cases using assertFalse, assertTrue etc is working, only hamcrest matching is giving errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually add the jar from [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg:%22org.hamcrest%22%20AND%20a:%22hamcrest-core%22)

Add it to your libs folder.

Right click the jar, and click add as library.

I had the same issue with getting it to find junit. Looks like Gradle is not doing its job.

I have filed a bug report, Please star:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=209832&thanks=209832&ts=1463161330

Comment: Thanks, only this solution worked. Just need to add dependencies {
    compile files('libs/hamcrest-all-1.3.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

Comment: Yea. I suspect you have modified sourceSet in your gradle file yes?

Comment: Yes! how is it related?

Comment: I think its a bug in gradle. If you had modified source sets, `androidTestCompile` doesn't work